# API docs for "stack overflow" still feature v1.0 docs

Tags: bug, documentation

I guess I'd call this a doc bug.

Currently the page http://api.stackoverflow.com redirects to http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage, which says at the top "Don't use 1.0, use 2.1".  This URL should really point to http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/.

Also, for those of us who don't bother reading 4 sentences when we think we see an answer in the first sentence, the first link off the 1.0 doc page saying "don't use this, use the new one" hyperlinks "v2.1" to a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-no-longer-beta/) announcing the launch, not the current docs.  The blog post *also* doesn't have an obvious link to the current docs.

So anybody googling "stack **overflow** api" has to do way more work than they should to find the docs.  Note that this problem doesn't happen for people looking for "stack **exchange** api".

Am I missing something?  How to correct these issues?

Comment: Note: site-specific domains (`api.stackoverflow.com`) only existed for v1.x of the API, so pointing them to v2.0 pages would be a little... inconsistent.